# Angular 2, reset form before navigate

Tags: angular2-routing, angular2-forms

I have an onSubmit method.

```
    onSubmit() {

    let user = this.form.value
    this._userService.postUser(user)
    this.form.reset();
    this._router.navigate(['users'])
}
```

I'm using

```
    this.form.reset();
```

to prevent dirty tracking but when I use this line it seems to disable

```
  this._router.navigate(['users'])
```

If I don't reset the form I have a dirty tracking alert message.

Is there any way I can have my cake and eat it?

Answer (score 1):

I should have used

```
this.form.markAsPristine()
```

instead of

```
this.form.reset()
```